# How to find the end of a linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, null, linked-list

We are creating LinkedLists in our data structures class. The following is the declaration for the class.

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    T m_data;                  // Data to be stored
    LinkedList<T>* m_next;     // Pointer to the next element in the list

    // ...
};
```

The teacher told us which functions to implement. I am currently trying to implement this:

```
// Purpose: accessor function for last element node
// Returns: pointer to the last element's node in the list; 
//     returns NULL if list is empty
LinkedList<T>* getLastPtr();
```

I am not sure what code you need to see, so here is a minified version of my code which demonstrates the problem:

```
template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    T m_data;
    LinkedList<T>* m_next;

    LinkedList() : m_next(NULL) {}

    void insert_front(const T& x);
    LinkedList<T>* getLastPtr();
}

// INSERT FRONT
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::insert_front(const T& x){
    LinkedList<T> *tmp;
    tmp = new LinkedList<T>;
    tmp->m_data = m_data;
    tmp->m_next = m_next;

    this->m_next = tmp;
    this->m_data = x;   
}

// GET LAST POINTER
template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>* LinkedList<T>::getLastPtr(){
    const LinkedList<T>* runner;
    const LinkedList<T>* tmp; //one behind runner
    runner =  this;
    while (runner->m_next != NULL){
        tmp = runner;
        runner = runner->m_next;
        cout<<"tmp: "<<tmp->m_data<<endl; //FIX DIS
        cout<<"runner: "<<runner->m_data<<endl; //FIX DIS
    }
    return tmp->m_next; 
}
```

We are also given a tester but for sake of simplification I will only post the section I am having issues with:

```
LinkedList<int> A;

//TEST : Inserting 13 numbers to a
cout << endl << "TEST : Inserting 13 numbers into A" << endl;
for (int k=0; k<13; k++){
    A.insert_front(k*2);
} 

// TEST : Acessing last element
cout << endl << "TEST : Acessing last element" << endl;
LinkedList<int>* p = A.getLastPtr();
cout << "Last = " << p->m_data << endl;
```

My issue is that when I use the function getLastPtr() it returns a bunch of random numbers. I do not know what I am doing wrong since my getAtPtr() function works properly and I am using almost identical code.

I think it has something to do with pointing to the wrong thing OR my last element isn't pointing to NULL (which should be for checking purposes).

Here you can see a demo of the problem: http://ideone.com/mDXKsV

Comment: I found one issue (but it isn't everything...): Try `return runner;` instead of `return tmp->m_next;`. Why is your return wrong? For example, consider the empty list: you access `tmp->m_next` but `tmp` is uninitialized in this case!

Comment: The main problem is with how you represent an empty list. Think about the difference of an empty list and a list with single element in your implementation. How many `LinkedList<T>` objects exist in each case? Or differently worded: What's the meaning of a linked list which has a null next pointer? Does it hold an element? ;) You need to change something about that...

Comment: @leemes Yeah actually i just noticed it was handling empty lists wrong so i am going to look at how i am inserting and more importantly how it handles the empty list. EDIT: also using return runner; throws an ERROR for invalid conversion.

Comment: About the `return runner`: You can remove the `const` from your `runner` declaration so it should work. But I just noted that you can fix everything by returning yet something different. Try to find out what! (And it has to do with how you represent the tail of your list...)

Comment: P.S. I simplified your code a lot. It still shows the issue when being compiled, so I hope it is okay that a lot was removed. I also added a demo link so people can see what is actually happening.

Comment: @leemes AH yeah removing const and then removing tmp variable makes the code a lot easier to read. I am still looking into whats wrong with my tail.

Comment: One more hint: Think about what's the data of the element which has a null next pointer! Try to find out (on paper) what's happening when you insert a single element into an empty list. How many elements exist? (There are two!) Where is the data?

Comment: @leemes not going to lie, i do not know what i am doing wrong. I know its something to do with inserting in the front and my get last pointer but i am now very lost after trying several ideas.

Comment: @SecretShop - `now very lost after trying several ideas`  Are you trying these ideas on paper first?  The way you're supposed to approach these exercises is to draw on paper a linked list with boxes, lines, links, etc.  Then you write the code according to the design.  If the code doesn't work properly, you look at the design on paper to see where your code goes awry, or if your design is wrong, redo the design.  You never write code akin to throwing stuff on the wall and hoping something sticks.

Comment: @paulMcKenzie Yes, i currently have a piece of paper and pencil in front of me and i am drawing out the diagrams in order to check it visually. i promise i am not haphazardly writing random code in hopes of it working.

Comment: @SecretShop - Well, you should start off with inserting only 3 items (not 13 items), printing the list from head to tail to make sure the insertions work, and then debug the getLastPtr().

Comment: @paulmckenzie alright so i found out that getLastPtr has an issue. it goes to the last box (which points to NULL) and returns its element (which is gibberish). Now making the NULL pointing box have an element won't fix anything because then there is no way to tell if it an empty list or a list with one element. My question now is how should i go about this?

Comment: Thank you for all the help! i finally fixed  it. it was much simpler than i originally thought and i was overlooking it the entire time. My apologies for all the questions. My thanks though for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

in getLastPtr() i was going to the last element in the list which pointed to NULL. I was originally grabbing data from THAT point and therefore it was gibberish. I learned that i had to grab the element behind the Null so i made a follower to the runner, but i also cleaned up a bunch of my code especially for insert_first.